# AspectJ before spring boot starts

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

Suppose i have a spring boot application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public abstract class AbstractMicroServer {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        // here some asppect should start
        final SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(AbstractMicroServer.class);
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

My aspectJ class

```
@Aspect
public class AOP{

    @Pointcut("execution(* org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.ignoreResourceType(..)")
    public void intercept() {
    }

    @Around("intercept()")
    public Object intercept(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        return joinPoint.getArgs();
    }
}
```

I want this Aspect to be ready before spring boot starts. Is this possible what i want to do ? The aspect is not getting intercepted for some reason which i dont know.

POM

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.12</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.12</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        </dependency>

      <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.10</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.java</include>
                            <include>**/*.aj</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <!-- use this goal to weave all your main classes -->
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                                <!-- use this goal to weave all your test classes -->
                                <goal>test-compile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

I am not using spring boot starter aop. Above are all the configuration and code i have for aop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Spring AOP

### Runtime Weaving

The Spring AOP is based on **runtime weaving** due to the proxy-based nature of the Spring framework. This means the target class is turned into a proxy during Spring runtime.

In most cases, the Spring framework doesn't make a proxy of its frameworks classes. The class you are interested, `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`, is not proxied. Therefore, Spring AOP cannot intercept any calls to `ignoreResourceType` method of `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`.

However, it doesn't mean you are out of luck. You can still take advantage of AspectJ's **binary weaving**.

## AspectJ

### Binary Weaving

In binary weaving, the target and aspect source code (*.java) are compiled separately into binary classes (.class). The binary classes are then woven together with AspectJ compiler (ajc).

In your case, the aspect source code (`AOP.java`) will be compiled with AspectJ compiler into a binary class (`AOP.class`). The `AOP.class` and the existing Spring class, `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.class` will be weaved to together into a new weaved `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.class`.

#### Code Before Weaving

Here is the code snippet of `ignoreResourceType` method of class `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`,

```
public void ignoreResourceType(String resourceType) {
        Assert.notNull(resourceType, "Ignored resource type must not be null");
        this.ignoredResourceTypes.add(resourceType);
}
```

#### Code After Weaving

Now, notice the changes after the method is woven by AspectJ.

```
public void ignoreResourceType(String resourceType) {
        JoinPoint var3 = Factory.makeJP(ajc$tjp_0, this, this, resourceType);
        SpringFrameworkClassAspect var10000 = SpringFrameworkClassAspect.aspectOf();
        Object[] var4 = new Object[]{this, resourceType, var3};
        var10000.adviceAround((new CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AjcClosure1(var4)).linkClosureAndJoinPoint(69648));
}
```

## How to achieve AspectJ Binary Weaving?

- You can generate binary weaving with the help of [Mojo's AspectJ Maven plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/).
- You will still need your aspect class.
- Make sure to include `spring-context` dependency under `weaveDependencies`.

Below is an excerpt from the plugin section of your project's `pom.xml`. You can find a complete working example [here](https://github.com/indrabasak/stackoverflow-indra/tree/master/spring-aspectj-example).

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
            <configuration>
                <showWeaveInfo/>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <complianceLevel>${java.version}</complianceLevel>
                <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                <forceAjcCompile>true</forceAjcCompile>
                <sources/>
                <weaveDirectories>
                    <weaveDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</weaveDirectory>
                </weaveDirectories>
                <weaveDependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                </weaveDependencies>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want to intercept method execution in Spring classes. For that, you have two options:

- Use load time weaving (`-javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver-<version>.jar` as a JVM argument)
- Weave your Spring library classes at build time to create a special weaved version of the library ([see relevant aspectj-maven-plugin documentation](http://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/examples/weaveJars.html)), and use the resulting weaved classes instead of the original spring jar files. Your resulting configuration would look similar to this:

  ```
  <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
          <weaveDependencies>
              <weaveDependency>
                  <groupId>org.agroup</groupId>
                  <artifactId>to-weave</artifactId>
              </weaveDependency>
              <weaveDependency>
                  <groupId>org.anothergroup</groupId>
                  <artifactId>gen</artifactId>
              </weaveDependency>
          </weaveDependencies>
      </configuration>
  </plugin>
  ```